# CSS table's text-align overwriting specific cell's text-align?

Tags: html, css

I want my whole table to have "center" text-align, besides some specific cells to have "right" text-align.  In my code, the one cell is being more specifically targeted by CSS, yet the more general assignment is overriding.  Why is this and how do I fix it?

```css
.data td {
    text-align: center;
}
.animal {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Type of Animal</th>
        <th>Favorite Food</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="animal">Cat</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS selectors are interpreted from least to most specific, so increase the specificity of your CSS selector to get it working.

I would recommend against using `!important`, because it will make that CSS more difficult to add to / override in the future.

There is also a [helpful MDN article on CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), which may help you understand why your CSS isn't overriding other rules as you would expect.

```css
.data td {
    text-align: center;
}
.data td.animal {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Type of Animal</th>
        <th>Favorite Food</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="animal">Cat</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The .data td will be overriding .animal as it has more control Make similar

```css
.data td {
    text-align: center;
}
.data .animal {
    text-align: right ;
}
```

```html
<table class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Type of Animal</th>
        <th>Favorite Food</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="animal">Cat</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```